# How to fix 'Object of class could not be converted to string' error when creating a form in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm making a really simple form with Symfony to add a color to the database. It's working great when using `createFormBuilder` in my Controller, but throws an error when using `createForm` with the `Type` I made. This is the error I get: *An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Color could not be converted to string")*.

I followed [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) line by line, I also tried some solutions given here to others who had kind of the same problem  (adding the `__toString` method to my Entity, for example), but nothing works.

**Entity**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ColorRepository")
 */
class Color
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=190, unique=true)
     */
    private $code;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    public function setCode(string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function new(Request $request)
    {
        $color = new Color();

        $form = $this->createForm(ColorType::class, $color);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
             $color = $form->getData();

             $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
             $entityManager->persist($color);
             $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('colorNew');
        }

        return $this->render('color/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

**Form**

```php
class ColorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'couleur',
            ])
            ->add('code', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'code couleur',
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'ajouter la couleur'])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Color::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Template**

```php
{% extends 'layout/base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    Ajouter une couleur
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I expect it to render two text inputs with their respective label and a submit button, instead it throws the error I mentioned. I got it to work at some point by commenting `$color = new Color();` in my Controller and thus not passing `$color` as an argument to the `createForm` method, but it was rendering not only the two text inputs and the submit button, but also a color input at the beginning of the form... (which I didn't ask for).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sure seems like you copied the code from the docs.  The error seems to be coming from the template.  Try reducing your template to just {{ form(form) }} That color input that you mentioned sort of implies you might have extra stuff in your template.

Comment: My template has already only `{{ form(form) }}` ... I've added my post to show how my template looks.

Comment: Very mysterious.  Symfony version? Double check all your namspaces and use statements are correct.  And that you are editing the same code that is being tested (it happens).  Just grasping here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was actually a bit interesting.

Symfony already has a ColorType.  You would not expect that creating your own ColorType would matter as the fully qualified class name should be used if anything really wanted to know if ColorType was being used.  But no, only the ColorType string is used for the default form templates.  Never encountered it before.

The solution is simple.  Rename ColorType to something like MyColorType and all should be well.

And it might have helped if the first line of the exception trace had been included in your question:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Color could not be converted to string").
in vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig (line 17)
```

Maybe not but that is what keyed me to the problem when I reproduced the test case.

Comment: the alternative is to add a blockprefix and add a template that is actually always used when the custom ColorType is being used. might be easier in symfony 4.3 when it's released